# Trouble sorting through an Object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

Hey guys I'm having trouble looking through an object array.  In short I have no idea how to. My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalorieCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner letterInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calories[] array = {new Calories("spinach", 23), new Calories("potato", 160), new Calories("yogurt", 230), new Calories("milk", 85),
            new Calories("bread", 65), new Calories("rice", 178), new Calories("watermelon", 110), new Calories("papaya", 156),
            new Calories("tuna", 575), new Calories("lobster", 405)};
    System.out.print("Do you want to eat food? ");
    String answer = letterInput.nextLine();
    while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        System.out.print("What kind of food would you like?");
        String answer2 = letterInput.nextLine();

        }


            }//end if

        }//end while loop
    }//end main method

}//end CalorieCalculator class



class Calories{
private String name;
private int calorie;


Calories(String name, int calorie){

    this.name = name;
    this.calorie = calorie;

}

public int getCalorie(){
    return this.calorie;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

}

I'm trying to look for the first argument, which is a string, in an element of the array.  For example, if someone types spinach, I want to look for the keyword spinach and also return the second argument, which is the calories of the spinach.

Comment: "In short I have no idea how to." how to... what?

Comment: @CyrilleKa how to sort through an object array to find a specific argument

Comment: It looks like you already know how to loop. So, iterate through every object in the array. At each iteration, test if the name of the current Calories object is equal to the String entered by the user. If it is, then print its calorie field.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the reply. the problem is I don't know what to write for the condition in the for loop.  If (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(?????))?

Comment: What do you want inside the ????? Presumably you want the different names of the Calories, right? You have a function to access this.

Comment: ????? depends on how you implement your loop. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these two variables you have in your code:

```
Calories[] array;
String answer2;
```

This is how I would find the calories that match the food named by "answer2":

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].getName().equals(answer2)) {
        return array[i].getCalorie();
    }
}
```

All this does is loop through the array of foods, and compares the input from the user with the name of each food. If a match is found, then it returns the calories of the food that was found.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array of elements and you are trying to find which element (instance of `Calories`) has the name that matches the input given by the user.

Give it a try, a for-loop will help you to go through the array and compare against the name of each... If you find any issues, please post here. We will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `array` variable, this method should do what you want:

```
 public Calories findCaloriesForFood(String food) {
    for (Calories calories : array) {
        if (calories.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(food)) {
            return calories;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: I just assumed the array was a static member or a class variable

Comment: It isn't; it's scope is in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

Your while loop and if loop are kind of redundant. I say that because, you start off with your "WHILE" loop checking for all input which is not N or NO, and then check for Y or Yes. Instead why not just check for Y or Yes in your while loop. So, in that case you only ask for what food he wants if he types Y or yes and exits for all other text inputs.

Secondly,

You are using a single dimensional array. So, each addition into the array is stored with an index. In your case, index  0 would have spinach, 1 for potato and so on. So in order to retrieve an object from the array, you need to specify its index and then fetch it. Once you have the object, all you need to do to fetch the value in it, is to use its getter methods.
The logic in your case would be to iterate through the array and check each name against the input text and when you find the match, thats the object you need.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in a case like this is use an "enum" called Food.

```
    public enum Food
    {
            SPINACH(23),
            ...
            LOBSTER(405);

            private int calories;

            private Food(int pCalories)
            {
                calories = pCalories;
            }

            public int getCalories()
            {
                return calories;
            }
     }
```

You can then lookup the calories for a specific food like this:

```
String selectedFoodString = answer2;
Food selectedFood = Food.valueOf(selectedFoodString);
int selectedCalories = selectedFood.getCalories();
```

Another way to do this would be using a Map. The name of the food would be the "key" and the calories would be the "value." A Map would make lookups just as easy as an Enum. The difference is style, and how dynamic you need the list to be. If the list will never change, an enum is appropriate. If you need to dynamically load the list, a Map might be better.